# Shimano 11 speed road shifters with 10 speed hub?

Tags: hub

is it possible to use Shimano 11 speed road shifter with 10 speed hub/cassette?

if yes, how?

I have a set of Shimano Hydraulic 11 speed shifters but I don't want to upgrade hub to 11 speed. Is it possible to use the shifters in some way?
Checking online on compatibility I realized that pull in shifting is quite different between 10 and 11 simano road.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What number of speeds is the derailleur?

Comment: derailleur I have is 10 ( I have a 9 too I can use) or I could buy a 11

Comment: just want to keep the wheelset

Comment: I think you are gong to have to choose between the wheel and the shifters. I don't think there is a way to combine shifters and derailleurs/cassettes of different speeds

Comment: unfortunately I know...just hoped to find some secret out here :)
I will choose one ;)

Comment: If the hub is newer it might be compatible with 11 speed cassettes. To check, remove the cassette and see if  a ~3mm spacer sits beneath the cassette. If there is remove it to have an 11-speed hub. If there's no spacer the hub isn't 11-speed compatible.

Comment: Unfortunately the hub is a 10 speed max. I am looking into changing only the hub body.

Comment: Is it possible to change the freehub on the wheel to an 11-speed-compatible freehub?   Note several manufacturers support this, including DT Swiss.

Comment: Note: Shimano  11spd Ultegra 11T - 34T cassettes dish the largest cog to work with a 10 spd cassette (same as their 11spd mountain cassettes)

Comment: Yes, that's what I had seen Paul H

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use MTB 11 speed cassette on a 8-9-10 speed freehub body.
Although not officially compatible, the recently introduced 105 derailleur RD-R7000-GS can physically shift up to 42t cog, but Shimano introduced also a 11-34 11-speed cassette which fits 10-speed freehub body, so there's plenty to choose from in 2019.

Comment: I will look into the 105 derailleur you mention. It seems like a good solution. I was checking it, but yes, they do not say that it can go up to 42. In many cases even 36 is a reasonable cog.

Comment: Hey OndrejP, I actually can find the 105 derailleur RD-R7000 on ly in 11 speed, have you seen it anywhere for 10?

Comment: Paolo: R7000 is 11 speed, but I am using 11s shifters, 11s RD-R7000 and 10s cassette and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Ah, I had a feelig thatbthisnis what you meant and here it is. Cool. Thanks

Comment: This is going to be the first time I hear that a 11 speed mech works with 1 speed shifters.

Comment: Paolo: I have 11sp shifters and 11s mech. These parts can't be mixed between 10s and 11s (except Tiagra 4700).

Regarding the 10s cassette I was just curious if it will work as a transition from 10s shifters+cassette towards 11s shifters+cassette, and it turns out it really does work. After initial setup I didn't have to adjust it.

Comment: Ondrej this interesting, and probably I will give a try to the 4700 on my next order. Yes, I have made quite some researches on 10 and 11 speed, but this is very interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been widely discussed elsewhere, including [on Lennard Zinn's Technical FAQ blog](http://www.velonews.com/2015/03/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-10-11-speed-drivetrain-component-compatibility_362722).

A method involving removing one cog from an 11-speed cassette and setting the rear derailleur limit screws appropriately is described [here](http://darkspeedworks.com/blog-11speed.htm).  I am planning to do exactly this on a touring wheel built with a Shimano M765 mountain hub.

Comment: This is the right answer but should be expanded upon beyond a link.

Comment: What would be the benefit in so doing and who would it accrue to?

Comment: Kind of the idea with SE is for the answers to not be dependent on outside links staying around, and have the info be there in the answer in full. Usually answers that do that well are what tend to get upvoted etc. Not that it's not helpful to give someone the link they need to figure out their predicament.

Comment: Understood.  The problem of 10/11 speed compatibility will be around for some time, so hopefully those links will persist as they will remain relevant.

Comment: I appreciate the answers. I know the topic and I am actually quite informed about the links you have posted Tim.
On the other hand, the reason why I write questions on SE is precisely what Nathan is trying to explain:
the internet is a wide source, often things are difficult to find. As well I know that among who answers to the questions there are very knowledgeable people.
Those are the people who I had this question intended for.

Comment: ...like at a certain point somebody discovered that 9 speed MTB rear mech woked perfectly with 10 speed shifter (all Shimano), things that have changed a lot the habits of many tourers and given us bigger cassettes to use...

Comment: ....somebody will discover things about 11 speed soon. Or I hope so!

Answer (score -1):

I think it wouldn't work in a satisfying way. Not sure if the spaces of a 10 speed and an 11 speed cassette are equal, but even if, at least you lose your "lower boundary" which is never a good idea cause it might happen that you accidentally shift too low

Comment: didn't know that that works indeed by removing one cog as mentioned above. so sorry for the wrong answer!